# Class Using Lengthy Calculations - Reducing Overhead

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, class, oop

Suppose I have a class that has several properties which are calculation-based and could even rely on the existence of a shared class member... Say something like this as an example:

```
Public Class FakeClass
    Public Shared Property Needed As FakeObject
    Public Property Prop1 as Double
    Public Property Prop2 as Double

    Public Function Func1() As Double
        ' Lengthy calculation using some properties, etc
    End Function

    Public Function Func2() As Double
        ' Lengthy calculation involving <Func1>, some properties, etc
    End Function

    Public Function Func3() As Double
        ' Lengthy calculation involving <Func1> and needing <Needed>
    End Function
End Class
```

And an instantiated object can be called many times throughout the code, so I wouldn't like to have to keep re-calculating these values each time, **but**, at the same time, I also want to take into account the possibility that some of the properties may have changed in the code and, so, the methods should be re-run...

I was thinking about doing this using something along the lines of either:

1. For each method, creating a private Boolean such as `_RecalcFunc1`, and a private Double such as `_Func1Val` to have the final methods look something like:

   ```
   Private _RecalcFunc1 As Boolean = True
   Private _Func1Val As Double
   Public Function Func1() As Double
       If _RecalcFunc1 Then
           _Func1Val = ' Lengthy calculation
           _RecalcFunc1 = False
       End If
       Return _Func1Val
   End Function
   ```

   and

   ```
   Public Shared Property Needed As FakeObject = Nothing
   Public Function Func3() As Double
       If Needed Is Nothing Then
           Throw New InvalidOperationException("The ""Needed"" object is necessary to perform this calculation.")
       End If
       ' Lengthy calculation involving <Func1> and needing <Needed>
   End Function
   ```
2. I saw that there are things such as the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, but that seems to be to notify objects outside of the current one and seems like it would just be expensive to implement.

Is there a standard / correct way to do this? Or what method / pattern best takes this into account?

Also, even though the source code provided is in VB, I'm equally comfortable with VB / C# solutions.

Thanks!!!

Comment: you could set a DataChanged flag in the prop setters and then only recalc if it is True.  `INotifyPropertyChanged` is usually for telling some external party that a prop has changed such as telling a `BindingList` that a stored object's prop has changed.

Comment: Thanks, @Plutonix, so like my idea #1 pretty much??

Comment: except, you cant use auto properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a variable for each function you have and then the function should only return the variable corresponding to the function. Then in the property setter method you should call a private recalculate method to do your lengthy calculations and save it to the variable.

Here is the code to show what I mean:

```
public class FakeClass
{
    private double func1Result;
    private double func2Result;
    private double func3Result;

    public FakeClass()
    {
        func1Result = Double.MinValue;
        func2Result = Double.MinValue;
        func3Result = Double.MinValue;

        _property1 = Double.MinValue;
        _property2 = Double.MinValue;

        _neededObject = null;
    }

    private double _property1;
    public double Property1
    {
        get { return _property1; }
        set
        {
            if (_property1 != value)
            {
                _property1 = value;
                RecalculateFunc1Result();
            }
        }
    }

    private double _property2;
    public double Property2
    {
        get { return _property2; }
        set
        {
            if (_property2 != value)
            {
                _property2 = value;
                RecalculateFunc2Result();
            }
        }
    }

    private static FakeObject _neededObject;
    public FakeObject Needed
    {
        get { return _neededObject; }
        set
        {
            if (_neededObject != value)
            {
                _neededObject = value;
                RecalculateFunc3Result();
            }
        }
    }

    private double RecalculateFunc1Result()
    {
        // Check to make sure the values are not the default/invalid ones.
        if (_property1 == Double.MinValue ||
            _property2 == Double.MinValue)
        {
            func1Result = Double.MinValue;
            return func1Result;
        }

        //func1Result = Lengthy calculation involing some properties.

        return func1Result;
    }

    private double RecalculateFunc2Result()
    {
        // Check to make sure the values are not the default/invalid ones.
        if (_property1 == Double.MinValue ||
            _property2 == Double.MinValue)
        {
            func2Result = Double.MinValue;
            return func2Result;
        }

        //func2Result = Lengthy calculation involing some properties and 
        //   RecalculateFunc1Result() or func1Result.

        return func2Result;
    }

    private double RecalculateFunc3Result()
    {
        if (Needed == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                @"The ""Needed"" object is necessary to perform this calculation.");

        //func3Result = Lengthy calculation involving RecalculateFunc1Result()
        //   or func1Result

        return func3Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Truly, a **VERY** well-explained solution and awesome!!! - Thank you!! - Only question / thought... You put in the logic of `_property1 == Double.MinValue` I have to think about it more, but wouldn't it make more sense to have a recalculation boolean? I see that you recalculate in the setter, but just wondering if that might catch you in some places? Or are you sure that's a safe way of doing it?

Comment: If you don't like the `_property1 == Double.MinValue` option then you can make every `double` reference a `double?` reference and then check `_property1 == null` instead. If you go with the null option the in the constructor you will have to initialize everything to `null` and then in the setter pieces of the properties you will want to have something like `if (value != null && _neededObject != value)`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your computed values are read much more often than the values that they are dependent on are written to.  In such cases you can create an actual instance field for your dependent values and recalculate them *in the setter of any of the values that they are dependent on.

It also may be worth considering making this type immutable, rather than mutable, although this would be a significant breaking change, unlike the previous option.  Making the class immutable means you can always eagerly compute the derived values upon construction of the object without worrying about those cached values becoming stale.  You can then recreate a new instance of the whole object when the values do need to change.  Assuming the values aren't changing all that often, this could be preferable.

Comment: Makes perfect sense - So, to some degree, #1 as suggested by @Plutonix in the comments above, but preferred immutable!

Comment: One more question - Suppose these calculations are large / time-intensive, does it still make sense to do them at the time of object creation if it's immutable? This is more of something I'm just curious about...

Comment: @JohnBustos If it's pretty likely that you'll need it, you can do it eagerly.  If it's plausible that you won't, then you can defer the calculation until the firs time it is needed, sure.

Comment: ... Just wish I could borrow your brain for a few days!!! - As always, !!!!!THANKS!!!!!